# Error using A3_4 (line 6) Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab, input, arguments

This is my code:

```
%Activity 3.4 An object is thrown vertically with a speed vo reaches at
%height h at a time t.

function t = time(h,vo,g)

t = roots([0.5*g,-vo,h])

%Testing the function

test = time(100,50,9.81)
```

I've looked through different solutions but still can't figure out why I keep getting this error.

The error is happening on the line `t = roots([0.5*g,-vo,h])`.

Comment: What error are you getting? The above code looks just fine...

Comment: Are you calling the `time` function with 3 inputs?

Comment: You are probably pushing the Play button in the MATLAB editor.  Don't do that.  Forget that it even exists.  Define `h`, `v0` and `g` in your Command Prompt, then do `t = time(h, v0, g);` in the Command Prompt.  Again, do not push the Play button.

Comment: rayryeng, I entered `h`,`vo`, and `g` like you said, but when I got to run `t = time(h, v0, g);` I get the error: **Undefined function 'time' for input arguments of type 'double'.** And pragmatist1, my initial error in this is that I get the error saying `not enough input arguments`.

Answer (score 1):

Three comments:

1. You are probably pushing the Play button in the MATLAB editor. Don't do that. Forget that it even exists. Define `h`, `vo` and `g` in your Command Prompt, then do `t = time(h, vo, g);` in the Command Prompt. Again, do not push the Play button.
2. Make sure your working directory is set to where you defined the function `time`.  MATLAB can't find this function that you defined.  If you don't know how to do that, check out this from MathWorks: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html
3. Your error says it's trying to use a file called `A3_4`, yet your function is called `time`.  In other words,  It looks like you called your file `A3_4.m` yet **it needs to be called `time.m`**.  Make sure it's in a file called `time.m`, then try again. That's one of MATLAB's cardinal rules.    When you define a function, the function name **and file name** need to match.

Do all of those three steps in order, and you will be laughing and singing like these guys below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [kym-cdn.com](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/131/896/gaijin4koma2_peersblog_1200684608.jpg?1307579749))</sub>

Comment: Okay, I seem to have gotten my answers which are 7.4612 and 2.7324, but, I have another error that says: `Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware
that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Error in roots`